# Spinner Dropdown selection

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I have a spinner as drowdown, when i click on the spinner item i want to show my own selector.

The code i wrote is

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/regions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    style="@style/regionSpinnerTheme"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />

<style name="regionSpinnerTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.Spinner</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Spinner" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/tw_list_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/tw_list_dark</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">false</item>
```

I m getting a green color in selection .Please Help me.

Comment: So just add your own drawables. What's the problem?

Comment: They are not reflecting. i am getting that green color only.

Comment: Can you give an example of reflection eddect you want to get?

Comment: I want blue color when i click spinner dropdown.

Comment: please add `tw_list_dark.xml` to your question

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in adroid. One of many many unfixed bugs.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24922

And BTW: You should let out the intermediate step regionSpinnerTheme.
Something like:

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/regions"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="38dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
  style="@style/Widget.Spinner.Region"
  android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />


<style name="Widget.Spinner.Region" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/tw_list_dark</item>
</style>
```

But as said, this does not work due to bug.